# expected identifier before token (

Tags: c, pointers

I keep getting the error

```
error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
         if((familia->(hijos+i)->edad)>18)   
                     ^
```

I really can't solve it, the problem is in familia-> but i don't know how to fix it. 

These are the structs i am using, I think it should be enough to understand :(

```c
  typedef struct hijo{
     int va_a_la_escuela;
     int edad;
     int estaVacunado;          
     } hijo;

 typedef struct gasto{
 int vestimenta;
 int vivienda;
 int comida;    
 } gasto;

 typedef struct familia{
   int numero_de_hijos;  
   hijo* hijos;
   gasto* gastos;
int recibeBono;
 int revisada;  
 } familia;

 int verificarVacuna(familia* familia){
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < familia->numero_de_hijos; i++) {
        if(familia->(hijos+i)->estaVacunado==0)//LINE OF ERROR
          return 0;
      }
     return 1;
    }


//VERIFICACION DE EDAD DE HIJOS DE LA FAMILIA
int verificarEdad(familia* familia){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < familia->numero_de_hijos; i++) {
    if(familia->(hijos+i)->edad>18) //LINE OF ERROR
      return 0;
  }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `familia->(hijos+i)` to do? `(hijos+i)` is an expression and as such cannot be used to access a structure field.

Comment: Did you mean `(familia->hijos+1)-> edad ` ?

Comment: hijos is a struct, estaVacunadi and edad are fields of the struct hijos

Comment: @Sebas is it a struct or a *pointer* to (or an array-of) a sequence of (hopefully at least two) struct?

Comment: is this what you need if((familia->hijos[i]->edad)>18) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I assume that in `familia->hijos`, `hijos` is an array, so maybe you mean

  ```
  familia->hijos[i].estaVacunado
  ```
- Or probably you meant to use pointer arithmetic, which can be

  ```
  (familia->hijos + i)->estaVacunado
  ```
- Or if it's an array of pointers

  ```
  familia->hijos[i]->estaVacunado
  ```
- Or an array of pointers, using pointer arithmetic

  ```
  (*(familia->hijos + i))->estaVacunado
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You surely mean to be using a syntax like `familia->hijos[i]->edad`.

Comment: That is what I needed thanks all. I will keep trying to use the array notation for future times.

Answer (score 0):

The left operand of `->` is an expression; it must be a pointer to a struct or union.

The right operand of `->` is not an arbitrary expression; it can only be an identifier, and it must be the name of a member of the struct or union.

Your subexpression

```
familia->(hijos+i)
```

is therefore invalid. You probably want

```
familia->hijos
```

We know that `familia` is of type `familia*` (BTW, using the same name for an type and an object that's a pointer to that object can be confusing). Without seeing how your type `familia` is defined, it's not possible to be sure exactly what you should write.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the pointer syntax, you can also use `familia->*(hijos + 1)->estaVacunado`.

This is equivalent to `familia->hijos[i]->estaVacunado`